# Live wallpaper as app background

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Is it possible to add live wallpaper as background into an app?

Comment: The user's currently selected homescreen live-wallpaper, or a specific one?

Comment: No, I mean add a live wallwaper within an user app, not at homescreen

Comment: I understand in your app. But do you want to show a specific LiveWallpaper in your app, or show the current homescreen's live wallpaper in your app?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean my custom LiveWallpaper

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the live wallpapers are just SurfaceViews, so there should be no reason you can't include something like that in your app. Your going to need to have the live wallpaper in your actual application instead of grabbing it from your users phone though.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/CubeLiveWallpaper/index.html